# Slide effect is not working in react-owl-carousel after adding data dynamically to carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, animation, owl-carousel

I am using react-owl-carousel in my react js project.

Initially, I am loading 5 items through an API call and after that, I am doing an API call on the click of the next button to get the next data. The issue is the data is updating properly but the slide effect of the carousel is gone. I have tried to add animateIn option also but it didn't work.

I am also using slideBy option with value 5 to slide 5 images at once and get the next 5 images from API call.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Two things you can check

1) If the ```div```s are getting appended at the end of the already rendered list of ```div```s
2) Try setting up appropriate event and see if the event is taking place in the first place

Comment: Probably not the correct example: here is this chap adding stuff dynamically to it: https://codesandbox.io/s/9466rzovvp

Comment: @KarthikVenkateswaran This link is not useful for me as I have created carousel manually. I am doing it by using the OwlCarousel component.

Comment: Data are appending properly but just the actual slide effect of react-owl-carousel is missing. That effect is there if we use fixed static data. When I am adding data by making an API call on the click of the Next button at that time the effect is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Its is working fine for me.

You have to install react-owl-carousel correctly by using

> npm install react-owl-carousel

then configure the plugin in web-pack you can only do this ejecting the project using npm run eject.

write the below code in same place where I have marked.

```
plugins: [
    // other plugins,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),
],
```

[image: code image]

You can find the below code for reference.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';
import '../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import '../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    item : [1,2,3],
    divPush : []
  }

  showData = () => {
    let { divPush } = this.state
    this.state.item.map((data,index) => {
      divPush.push(<div
        style={{
          backgroundColor : "green",
          padding : 10
        }}
      >
        I am {index + 1} div
      </div>)
      this.setState({ divPush })
      console.log("I am printing")
      return(
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor : "green",
            padding : 10
          }}
        >
          I am {index + 1} div
        </div>
      )
    })
  }

  update = () => {
    let { divPush } = this.state
    let length = divPush.length
    divPush.push(<div
      style={{
        backgroundColor : "green",
        padding : 10
      }}
    >
      I am div {length}
    </div>)
    this.setState({ divPush })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div style={{
        width : "100%",
        height : "100%",
        display : "flex",
        flexDirection : "column"
      }}>

        <OwlCarousel
          className="owl-theme"
          loop
          margin={10}
          nav
        >

            {this.state.divPush.map((data) => {
              return(data)
            })}

        </OwlCarousel>
          <div
            style={{
              marginTop : 20
            }}
          >
          <button
            onClick={this.update}
        >
          Add new
        </button>
          </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I can't run npm run eject because my whole project is running on create-react-app and i can't take risk of ejecting it as it is large project. I can't find the reason of adding it in webpack because jQuery is already working in my project properly.

Comment: If jquery is running then it should work fine. Did you tried the reference code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but the main issue is with slide effect. Data are appending properly but just the actual slide effect of react-owl-carousel is missing. That effect is there if we use fixed static data. When I am adding data by making an API call on the click of the Next button at that time the effect is not there.

Comment: I don't know but for me it is working fine when I am updating state, you can check my example code.

Comment: The state is also updating in my case but the issue is with the slide effect. New data are appending but slide effect is not there.

Answer (score 0):

'Wait' for the dynamic data

```
class Room extends Component {
    state = { 
        product: {},
     }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await axios.get('https://product-backend/api/end-point')
        .then((response) => {
            const {data: product} = response.data;

            this.setState({product});
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
          if (error.response) {
            this.props.history.push("/not-found");
          }
        });
    }

    render() { 
        const {product} = this.state;

        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
                {product.photos && 
                   <OwlCarousel className='owl-theme' items={1} loop margin={10} nav> 
                       {product.photos && product.photos.map(photo =>
                           <div key={photo.id}>
                               <img className="img-responsive" src={product.photo_path + photo.photo} />
                           </div>
                        )}
                   </OwlCarousel>
                }
           </React.Fragment>
       )
}
```

The waiting is in `{product.photos && ...` line

Answer (score 0):

try using a key property on the owl carousel div like this:

```
  <OwlCarousel
                    className="owl-theme"
                    // loop
                    // margin={10}
                    // nav
                    items={3}
                    dots
                    mouseDrag={false}
                    stagePadding={0}
                    key={`carousel_${changingStateIdentifier}`}
             >
```

As suggested here:
https://hashnode.com/post/react-js-render-method-called-with-state-update-but-component-view-did-not-update-cjq7ohku100dm57s1yk6qvp56

This property also needs to be different before and after updating carousel content, so you can use another state variable to do that.